# Set combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Assume all strings of length 3 from the set S = {A,C,G,T}, (allowing repetition) are equally likely. What is the probability that such a string has no C given that it has no A?

Totally lost with this question.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, make an attempt?

Comment: How many of such strings are there having no $A$? How many of the strings having no $A$ have no $C$ either?

Answer (score 1):

The reduced sample space after '$A$' has been removed has $3^3$ unique strings. How many of them have no '$C$'? Then form the correct quotient.